# How to get the token attributes in Antlr-4 lexer rule's action

Tags: java, php, antlr, antlr4, antlr3

I am new to Antlr-4, but have some idea about Antlr-3, where the lexer could be created without the need of any parser rule; in order to match a lexer rule by matching some tokens like:

```
CLASS: 'Class' WS+ id=ID
{
System.out.println($id.text);
}
ID : [a-z]+ ;
WS : [ \r\t\n]+
```

How could I do this in Antlr-4 without any parser, since the Antlr-4 lexer does not allow using attributes in the rule's action?

Any idea/example will be helpful for me!

Comment: By using the antlr-4.7, Its giving the enough information about my question 

`warning(201): AntlrPLexer.g4:16:20: labels in lexer rules are not supported in ANTLR 4; actions cannot reference elements of lexical rules but you can use getText() to get the entire text matched for the rule
`

---------------------------------------------------------------------
By why Antlr 4,  discouraging the labels in lexer rules??

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ANTLR4 grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/antlr4/ANTLRv4Parser.g4#L233) you can certainly use a label in a lexer rule. Just create your standalone lexer grammar and feed that to ANTLR to have it generate your lexer class.

Comment: I did that but since Antlr-4 does no special $x attribute translations in lexer actions (unlike v3).  So unable to get the value of lexer rule like *$id.text* in the above example.

Comment: Did you try $ID instead, which is actually the ID rule context (htat least that's what I expect, can't check myself ATM.)?

Comment: $ID also not working, and getting the same error:

`error(128): AntlrPHPLexer.g4:210:27: attribute references not allowed in lexer actions: $ID.text`  
`1 error(s)`  

`BUILD FAIL`